# Getting total rows from current Super Table within Matrix Block (too many rows)

Tags: matrix, plugin-supertable

This is my first site in Craft CMS (coming from EE) and trying to get my head around a few things.

I've got a matrix field that defines various types of content - one of which is a 'Super Table' field. In this 'Super Table' field, I've got one particular field called 'linkText' which I'm trying to pull through. I did successfully BUT it came through 19 times. I've been trying to suss out where this number comes from.

I have a matrix field called 'pageContent'. The particular Block Type I'm looking at is called 'textBlock'. Within that block I then have a rich text field called 'Text' which pulls through perfect i.e. once as expected. I then have the troubled 'Super Table' field called 'callToAction' which has a linkType and linkText in there.

```
{% for block in entry.pageContent %}

    {% if block.type == "textBlock" %}

        {% for row in block.callToAction %}

             <p>{{ row.linkText }}</p>

        {% endfor %}

    {% elseif block.type == "customTable" %}

        etc, etc, 

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, it is late! ;) but been checking the docs for a while and can't solve it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome JonnyT - Do you have 19 rows in 'Call to Action' ?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. I just have one row but have since discovered it's because I had set 'Static' in the Super Table field. Not sure why that would return 19, I can guess that it's down to a static field being generic so has to be identified differently?! Strange!

Comment: Glad you figured it out man!

Answer (score 1):

In this case it was pulling through 19 rows only when 'Static Field' was selected. Everything was fine otherwise, possibly a way that the data was being pulled.